# In Robot Framework how do I pass PATH parameter for a REST API having its path parameter in following format {path}/getinfo

Tags: api, robotframework, path-parameter

Please provide the code format or syntax , by which I can pass the path parameter for API in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Some samples to use PATH in robotframewok]

Refer more options at - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#library-documentation-top
You must use Library Operating system to deal with File Path.

Comment: does this solve your problem?